# How to redirect to a new component in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, ngoninit

I am making an Angular component that the user accesses by clicking a link sent to their email, which contains their user id. I need to make it so that it automatically redirects them to the admin page if they have already completed their registration. However, it seems that using `router.navigate` inside the `ngOnInit` event doesn't work, giving the error

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded.

Here is the code:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.activatedroute.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.API.getUserData(params['id']).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    this.item = res;
    sessionStorage.setItem('USER_ID', this.item._id);
    if (res["registry_complete"]){
      this.router.navigate(['/user-admin']);
    } else {
    }
  });
});
}
```

How do I accomplish this?

EDIT: Despite what the error says, BrowserModule is only imported once, in the main module. If the "this.router.navigate(['/user-admin']);" is removed, the code runs fine. It also runs fine outside of the ngOnInit or constructor functions. I suspect the reason for this error is because router.navigate attempts to load the main module again, and since the page is in the middle of loading it therefore imports BrowserModule twice - but if this is the case, how *does* one redirect this way in Angular?

EDIT: It was actually a problem in the user-admin routing module.

Comment: Can you post your app.module?

Comment: you should perform this inside constructor instead of ngOnInit.

Comment: @Radwojt The same thing happens if it is done inside the constructor.

Comment: This error has nothing to do with ngOnInit. Search for BrowserModule in your app. It should be imported only once. If it occurs twice, remove th elater occurence,

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari BrowserModule is only imported once. If the "this.router.navigate" is removed, it runs fine. If "this.router.navigate" is run outside of NgOnInit or the constructor, it also runs fine.

Comment: @IndigoFenix Okay. In that case, what is the reason that you are not sending the link directly for the required component in your email. You can check all your conditions there too.

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari User convenience. Do you mean to say that Angular *cannot* handle a simple page redirect?

Comment: Definitely not. The error you have shared has to do with the loading of the modules. May be check all your routing and module declaration. Regardless, if my motive was to open up a page for a user, i would rather redirect the user directly to that page instead of showing the browser navigation (route change) after the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that somehow, you've imported `BrowserModule` in your apps more than once. As specified in [docs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#should-i-import-browsermodule-or-commonmodule), the `BrowserModule` module must be imported in the root module of the app:

> Do not import BrowserModule in any other module. Feature modules and 
>   lazy-loaded modules should import CommonModule instead. They need the 
>   common directives. They don't need to re-install the app-wide providers.

Also, `NoopAnimationsModule` and `BrowserAnimationsModule` contain `BrowserModule`, so if you're importing one of them, you need to remove importing  `BrowserModule` (if you have one).

Comment: BrowserModule is only imported once, in the root module. I suspect that attempting to redirect while initializing the page may *call* the root module (since it's trying to load a new component) and doing this while the page is in the middle of loading may cause it to be imported twice, triggering this error.  But if that's the case, how *do* you redirect to a new page?

Comment: IndigoFenix, can you add to your question the route module for loading component by path `/user-admin`, and module to which this component imported

Comment: You're right, it was a problem in the user-admin routing module.

Answer (score 0):

Check what modules are you importing `.module.ts`

If You are use `BrowserAnimationsModule`

place it before `BrowserModule`

and check what are imports of sub modules